# Failed to connect to MySql at 127.0.0.1:3306

Tags: mysql

In a new MySQL Workbench; while creating a connection It keeps giving me an error :
" Failed to connect to MySql at 127.0.0.1:3306 ; can't connect to MySql server on '127.0.0.1'(10061)

Comment: Have you tried connecting via the command prompt?  Have you tried using `netstat` to see if MySQL be listening at port `3306` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I tried `netstat -nl|grep 3306` but I can't see anything listening in the port

Comment: The comment by @Harish may be correct.  You might have to start your MySQL instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its seams your database ie (mysql) not started,
check the mysql official [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-start-service.html), how to start mysql server.
If you already install the mysql server follow the below process.

[Your mysql server installation directory location]/bin\mysqld" --install

Comment: also try reinstalling

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had a previous mySQL server installation (with non-standard port), and I re-installed to a different directory & port. Then I got the same issue. To resolve, you click on home + add new connection.

If you need to know the port of your server, you can find it when you start My SQL command line client via All Programs -> MySQL ->  MySQL ServerX.Y  -> MySQL X.Y Command Line Client and run command status (as below)

[image: how to create]

[image: how to find port]

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between 127.0.0.1 and localhost. In all likelyhood your user is setup to access the database on "localhost". If that doesn't work, verify the user you're connecting with can access 127.0.0.1 via the CLI ( IE mysql -uroot -p -h127.0.0.1 ).

Comment: It helped for me